# How can I play a sound in Console Application in a For loop to sound like somebody is typing?

Tags: c#, audio, console-application

My biggest problem is that it is only played once in the end of the loop. I was wondering if there is a Pause for loop to play a sound and then continue the loop but I can't find anything like this.

```
class Feladat
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    int seconds = 3;

    public void Udv()
    {
        player.SoundLocation = "./sounds/type2.wav";
        Console.WriteLine();
        string szoveg = "Üdvözöllek !";

        for (int i = 0; i < szoveg.Length; i++, System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.050)))
        {               
            string current = Convert.ToString(szoveg[i]);
            System.Console.Write(current);
            player.Play();
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Comment: A tip: remove *everything* not necessary from the code. I haven't brought your code to my editor but a visual inspection dells me `seconds`, `dt`, `Kozep();` or `Console.writeLine();` are used at all for the task of playing a sound in a loop.

Comment: Also, don't bother converting the character to a `String` before writing it. `Console.Write()` can take a character.

Comment: Hi, just tested your code on my machine with a sample.wav and a longer time (2 seconds) and it works just fine. 

maybe the time is to short for your wav to be played?

Comment: @RolandDeschain my .wav file is  0.05 sec

Comment: @BrootsWaymb  Error code appears if  I delete
Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'

Comment: ok and it doesn't help if you make the time between each interval 0.1 seconds?

Comment: @RolandDeschain I tested with your 2 sec and it worked, but with 0.1 sec it is not.

Comment: @RolandDeschain Tested with 0.15 sec and worked. Maybe 0.05 is too fast to be played ?

Comment: @SándorPató - That's weird... Out of curiosity, are you using something other than the .NET Framework by chance? A `char` override should be available in all framework and Core versions, plus almost all .NET Standard versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I put an answer, which seems a good explanation based on the players article on the microsoft docs. 
Maybe someone can confirm this? (or give a better reason)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb In my test I just used `Console.Write(szoveg[i])` no problem whatsoever

Comment: @BrootsWaymb No, I'm not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to Cut off the start of the .wav file, because it was too long for the play intervall. Problem Solved !

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.play?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The Play method plays the sound using a new thread. If you call Play before the .wav file has been loaded into memory, the .wav file will be loaded before playback starts. You can use the LoadAsync or Load method to load the .wav file to memory in advance. After a .wav file is successfully loaded from a Stream or URL, future calls to playback methods for the SoundPlayer will not need to reload the .wav file until the path for the sound changes.

Seems loading is not done in time your loop iterates again.

Comment: I had to Cut off the start of the .wav file, because it was too long for the play intervall. Problem Solved !

Comment: Ok, in that case this isn't the answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try moving 'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.050))' from the loop to after `player.Play();` and tell us if it helps.

Comment: Why would this help? It would execute at the same(-ish) time.

Comment: Only played Once in the end of the whole loop.  And not (szoveg.Length) times.